# Почему не отображается мобильное меню на ios?

Tags: javascript, css

Не могу понять, почему на айфонах не отображается мобильное меню при нажатии на гамбургер. На остальных девайсах все норм. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот сайт http://inoi2000.tmweb.ru

код открывающий меню

```
 $(".js-menu-burger").click(function() {
        var e = $(this)
          , t = $(".js-nav")
          , o = $(".js-header")
          , s = $(".wrapper-content")
          , n = $(".js-header").outerHeight();
        o.toggleClass("is-fixed"),
        o.hasClass("is-fixed") ? s.css({
            "padding-top": o.outerHeight()
        }) : s.removeAttr("style"),
        s.toggleClass("overflow"),
        e.toggleClass("is-active"),
        t.toggleClass("is-active").css({
            top: n
        }),
        t.hasClass("is-active") ? t.css({
            visibility: "visible"
        }) : setTimeout(function() {
            t.css({
                visibility: "hidden"
            })
        }, 500)
    })
```

Comment: А что у вас в коде мы должны угадать? Или наугад ответ дать? Прикрепите код.

Comment: p.s Хотя бы тот код, который что-то делает при нажатии на "бурегер"

Comment: Тестируете на настоящем устройстве, или на каком-то симуляторе? У меня в Safari на IPhone меню по нажатию вполне себе отображается

Comment: Решил проблему убрав overflow в .header